# Unload protocols from pcap

Tags: wireshark, tshark

How can i use the `tshark` utility to download a list of `protocols` from a `.pcap` file? Only `protocols` are needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the fastest way but should output what you need.

The following line will output a CSV file

```
 tshark -r file.pcap -E header=y -E separator=, -T fields -e frame.protocols > file.csv
```

And then you can use the following Python code

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
 new = df["frame.protocols"].str.split(":",expand = True)
 pd.value_counts(new.values.ravel())
```

You can see the number of occurrences of each protocol.

P.S. Ignore *eth* and *ethertype*

Comment: Thank you very much.
Apparently I asked the question the wrong way, because this command outputs the protocol for each packet to me.
`eth:ethertype:ip:udp:rtp
eth:ethertype:ip:udp:rtp
eth:ethertype:ip:ip
eth:ethertype:ip:ip
eth:ethertype:ip:ip`

how would I make it output the name of the protocol and how many times it occurs in this dump?

Comment: Hello @AlexRebell, could you elaborate more, what do you mean by the name? Do you mean for example IP = Internet Protocol?

Comment: @AlexRebell It would be appreciated if you can explain the output you need by giving an example of the needed output

Comment: Hello! I need an approximate result like this:
Protocol and its number (i.e. how many times it occurs in network traffic)
for example: `SHH - 15; Telnet - 20;` and so on.
Thank you

Comment: @AlexRebell I edited the answer, please check it. Please do not hesitate to comment back if you need any help

Comment: Super, what you need. Please correct your answer, it should not be `frame.protocol`, but `frame.protocols`. thank you very much

Comment: Thank you @AlexRebell for letting me know about the typo. Hope it worked for you.